# Altair word map filtering by years not working

Tags: python, altair, vega-lite, vega

I have a problem with filtering data based on 'year' column values. I have a drop-down with every year starting from 1950 to 2013, and when I change the value in the dropdown map should rerender with new data, but it doesn't. The map only renders for 2013 year (last group in dataset).

**Here is code:**

```
years = pd.unique(seasonData['year'])
seasons = ['yearAvg', 'summerAvg', 'winterAvg']
#map selector
selectorYear = alt.selection_single(
    name='Years',
    fields=['year'],
    bind=alt.binding_select(options=years, name="Year"),
    init={'year': '1951'},
)
selectorSeason = alt.selection_single(
    name='Temperature for',
    fields=['column'],
    bind=alt.binding_select(options=seasons, name="Seasons"),
    init={'column': 'yearAvg'},
)
base = alt.Chart(geoDF).mark_geoshape(
  fill = '#bfdff7', stroke = 'white', strokeWidth = 1
).transform_lookup(
    lookup='name_long',
    from_= alt.LookupData(seasonData, 'Country', ['yearAvg', 'summerAvg', 'winterAvg', 'year', 'Country'])
).transform_fold(
    seasons, as_ = ['column', 'value']
).encode(
    tooltip = [alt.Tooltip('value:Q', title='Temperature', format='.2f'), alt.Tooltip('Country:N', title='Country'), alt.Tooltip('year:N', title='year')],                                                 #-40,    -20,       0,             5,       10,       15,        20,            25,   30,         35,           40,    50
    fill = alt.Fill('value:Q', title='Avarage temperature by county', scale=alt.Scale(type="linear", domain=[-40, -20, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 50], range=['#00f', '#2424f7', '#2ad8ff', '#8fe0ff', '#f3ff8f', '#fff18f', '#ffc254', '#ff9354', '#ff6c54', '#fd553a', '#fd1a1a', '#f00'] )) 
).add_selection(
    selectorYear,
    selectorSeason
).transform_filter(
    selectorYear & selectorSeason
).properties(
   width = 1000, height = 650,
   title='World map of temperature data (1950 - 2013)'
)
base
```

**Here is how data looks:**

[image]

**Here is how the chart looks:**
[image]

**And if I change year in the dropdown the chart goes black.**
[image]

**What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?**

Comment: A version of this question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64235215/2937831. If you would like an answer specific to your question, please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

The solution described in a comment from [@jakevdp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2937831/jakevdp)  works. Just change data frame passed to the chart function with data frame passed to LookupData like so:

```
base = alt.Chart(seasonData).mark_geoshape(
  fill = '#bfdff7', stroke = 'white', strokeWidth = 1
).transform_lookup(
    lookup='Country',
    # from_= alt.LookupData(seasonData, 'Country', ['yearAvg', 'summerAvg', 'winterAvg', 'year', 'Country'])
    from_= alt.LookupData(geoDF, 'name_long', ['scalerank', ...... , 'geometry'])
)
```

But for proper rendering, I needed to include (**fields** argument of LookupData function) all fields from geo df. Adding only geometry doesn't work.